# How to import shapefile to PostgreSQL via PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager?

Tags: postgis

When I after opened shapefile and click to button Import Log Window gives back error message:

> dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened. Shapefile import failed.

I try to open the dbf file and still repeat the error message.

Comment: Is the dbf file present?

Comment: Is other software capable of opening this very shapefile? Qgis for example?

Comment: In QGIS is the shapifile normal viewed.